# How to sort horizontal partitioned data

Tags: java, sorting, database-partitioning

I have a telco billing software system. In it there are daily logs of users' calls. The logs are horizontally partitioned by date (month). Each partition is stored in a separate database and may be spread over multiple instances.

In the UI the user will specify a date range. The data returned can be sorted on any field. The date range may span over multiple partitions. The application must support paging through the date range's data.

I cannot load too many records into memory for sorting. Putting sort inside the query only gives me sorted data inside one result-set.

So I need to sort data from multiple partitions which are each individually sorted. How can I return sorted records to the UI from multiple sorted result-sets?

**EDIT:** After more analysis on this problem, We have some more inputs. There is requirement of pagination also. Due to this we need to find out one more way to do realtime sorting on multiple resultsets.

Comment: You could only load the column that is to be sorted and the record ids, then sort and finally load the records you want to display based on the sorted ids. I'm not sure you could do any meaningful interleaving on a db-level so doing it in your code seems to be the easiest way. Another option might be to write the (partial) records into a memory-mapped file and sort there but that would probably cost even more performance - after all you have a classic speed-vs-memory situation here.

Comment: We discussed the first approach, but downside in this approach is we need to query again with Id's and since it is from UI, pagination also need to be achieved.

Comment: Well we had a similar situation where loading all data just took too much memory and thus we followed the approach of first loading only the data to be sorted as well as the ids, then sorting and keeping only the ids. Paging would then operate on the sorted ids and only the records corresponding to a page's ids would be loaded completely. Of course you'd need to query again but with paging you'd have to do that anyways. To speed up your second (paging) query you could store the source partition as well and only query those partitions.

Comment: he said "logs"!  he said "sort"!  Will someone say "hadoop"?

Comment: I think that @MK. gave a good hint. Store the data relevant to the query/sorting criteria externally together with ids in some cache, data grid, NoSQL database or something similar, and then query for ids from there. Alternatively, you could use stored procedures to avoid loading lots of data, but it may impose performance impact on the database. The third option is to maintain redundancy in the database directly, instead of in an external storage.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, please help to review the other solution we found.

Comment: Thanks @DraganBozanovic, please help to review the other solution we found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By relying on ResultSet's ability to load limited data in memory we are able to come up with a solution in Java using Dynamic Comparator. Solution is to take first record from each resultSet and sort it in java and return first element from sorted data.

**Detailed Solution:**

First we built a program which can give us a dymanic Comparator based on the criteria choosed on the screen.

Second We have written one AggregateResultSet wrapper over the DAO which is wrapping over ResultSets from different partitions. Note: these individual ResultSets are already sorted with same criteria. Then AggregateResultSet  will be given a dynamic comparator.

This AggregateResultSet will have a data structure to store first element of each result set initially. It will return the next element on call to next(). This element would be the element which comes first as per dynamicComparator. During next() call, We remove this element from temporary data structure and insert the next element from the same result set in the temporary data structure. This way AggregateResultSet will return data in expected order, by merging/storing/sorting very limited data in Java.

We hope to receive no comparison issues as we have mostly numeric/string data in sorting.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting solution which should reduce the memory overhead in the Java application. I'm not sure of the implications for the databases though since in theory you'd have to keep the connection open as well as keep the result in the db's cache in order to quickly retrieve the next element. Additionally you could run into transactional problems if data that the db keeps in its cache is updated.

Comment: @Thomas, since it is billing system, data(call records) gets uploaded only once(day+2) after data is reconciled at various levels, and never updated (security).

Comment: If I understand your solution correctly, paging will be very inefficient, since you would need to read all of `n-1` pages before the page `n`.

Comment: @draganbozanovic, we have a existing implementation of paging, I m trying to understand it. But as of now it needs input of resultset and few parameters.